# Rails user_authentication is not working, find method always returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to get my head around, this, I've been trying it for hours and it still doesn't seem to work, even though I've followed the tutorials available properly. I'm basically creating my own login validation with its own session controller. It has a form for a login and then some authentication steps. I'm using bcrypt to create hashes for passwords as well, I don't know if this is doing anything, or not, I suspect it isn't but still.

Here is the form I use:

```
    - provide(:title, "Sign in")
%h1 Log in
.row
  .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
    = form_for signin_path do |f|
      = f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email'
      = f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password', required: true
      = f.submit "Sign in"
    %p
      New user? #{link_to "Create New Account", new_user_path}
```

And here's my sessions controller:

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  require 'bcrypt'

  def new 
  end 

  def create
    #google_user = GoogleUser.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    #session[:google_user_id] = google_user.id
    #redirect_to '/users'
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to user, notice: 'Logged In'
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    #session[:google_user_id] = nil
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Logged Out'
  end
end
```

Ignore the google stuff, that's something that I will have to handle later, as it would seem.

I'm also not allowed to use any such as devise, or any of the others that make this process easier. I'd appreciate if someone could check my code and tell me if there's something wrong, because I certainly don't know what else to do with this.

Query parameters:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.email = 'email'
```

The problem with that query is that it is not taking the proper email, when I type, "email@gmail.com" it doesn't get that, it just grabs the symbol 'email'

Comment: Can you post the `params` that are generated in the server logs when you submit the `form`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have a mistake in your code:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:password])
```

should be:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

Comment: I fixed it but it is still not working. I don't know why it isn't catching it.

Comment: @Argus Please add an update to the question with the new code and error. Otherwise it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change:

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:password])
```

into

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
```

Answer (score 0):

change

`user = User.find_by_email(params[:password])`

to

`user = User.where(email: params[:email]).take`